# Macro to change values of the cell range to values only

Tags: vba, excel

`A1` has list that includes the 12 months of the year
`B2` to `M2` row are months – Jan to Dec
`B3` to `B7` categorizes that are scored each month

I want to program a button to do the following
When I click the button I want the macro to look up the month on cell `A1` in the cell range `B2:M2`. Then in the matching cell change the values on `row 3` to `row 7` values only. Right now `rows 3` to `7` are linked to other cells. I want them converted to values only.

E.g. If January is selected in `A1`. Then the macro would identify `B2` as January and changes values of `B3:B7` to Values only.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a collaborative site, not a "free outsourcing" site.

Comment: I havent got a clue on how to do this

Comment: What sort of Lookup are you trying? Vlookup? HLookup? Index? Match?  Try recording a macro while you perform the action manually. Then post the code. It would also help to include  a screenshot of your worksheet (upload an image to Imgur.com and give us the URL).

Comment: could you please upload a screen shot of excel file... I could not visualise what you are trying.

Comment: how do i upload a file

Comment: @user2441238, if you edit your post, there's a button to attach image files to your question.

Comment: @user2441238 You can upload image at [tinypic.com](http://tinypic.com/‎) and share the link.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I actually reckon a lot of the xl questions are homework as opposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this spreadsheet:

[image]

Input is in `A1`

To simplify things I've used a formula in `A2`: `=MATCH(A1,$B$2:$M$2,0)+1`

Then added the activex button called `PressMe`.

Right-clicking the button in design-mode and looking at "View code" I've got the following:

```
Private Sub cmdPressMe_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim colNumber As Integer
    colNumber = Me.Range("A2").Value
    With Me.Range(Me.Cells(3, colNumber), Me.Cells(7, colNumber))
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Me.Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

An alternative to the above that doesn't use the clipboard is the following:

```
Private Sub cmdPressMe_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim colNumber As Integer
    colNumber = Me.Range("A2").Value

    Dim firstRange As Range

    Set firstRange = Me.Range(Me.Cells(3, colNumber), Me.Cells(7, colNumber))
    firstRange.Value = firstRange.Value

Me.Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```